# How to prove the first derivative equals zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

The continuously differentiable function $f(x):\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for every $x\neq 0$.

> How to prove: $\displaystyle\left.\frac{{\rm d} f}{{\rm d} x}\right|_{x=0}=0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the left-handed limits of the derivative. They will show that the derivative is $\geq 0$ and $\leq 0$.

Comment: @Joanpemo, yes. thanks. will delete.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}
>0 & \text{for $h>0$}\\[6px]
\dfrac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}
<0 & \text{for $h<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
so
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}\ge0,
\qquad
\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}\le0,
$$
Hence…

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $f$ has a global minimum at $0.$ Therefore $f'(0)=0.$ (This does not require that $f$ be continuously differentiable; differentiability alone will give the result.)